# rspec Ruby on Rails uninitialized constant RecipesController::Recipes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

hello i'm doing some test of my application with Rspec (this is my very first time i'm using it)

this is my test file located in **spec/controllers/recipes_controller_spec.rb**:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe RecipesController do
  render_views
  describe "index" do
    before do
      Recipe.create!(name: 'Baked Potato w/ Cheese')
      Recipe.create!(name: 'Garlic Mashed Potatoes')
      Recipe.create!(name: 'Potatoes Au Gratin')
      Recipe.create!(name: 'Baked Brussel Sprouts')

      xhr :get, :index, format: :json, keywords: keywords
    end

    subject(:results) { JSON.parse(response.body) }

    def extract_name
      ->(object) { object["name"] }
    end

    context "when the search finds results" do
      let(:keywords) { 'baked' }
      it 'should 200' do
        expect(response.status).to eq(200)
      end
      it 'should return two results' do
        expect(results.size).to eq(2)
      end
      it "should include 'Baked Potato w/ Cheese'" do
        expect(results.map(&extract_name)).to include('Baked Potato w/ Cheese')
      end
      it "should include 'Baked Brussel Sprouts'" do
        expect(results.map(&extract_name)).to include('Baked Brussel Sprouts')
      end
    end

    context "when the search doesn't find results" do
      let(:keywords) { 'foo' }
      it 'should return no results' do
        expect(results.size).to eq(0)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

when i try to execute it by the command:

> bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/recipes_controller_spec.rb

i fail all my tests with this error:

```
Failure/Error: xhr :get, :index, format: :json, keywords: keywords
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant RecipesController::Recipes
     # ./app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:4:in `index'
     # ./spec/controllers/recipes_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

i've tried to look all my code but i haven't find out the error

Comment: It sits within your controller, line 4. Could you past this file as well?

Comment: Looks like you have `Recipes` instead of `Recipe` in `index` method of `recipes_controller`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NameError: uninitialized constant RecipesController::Recipes
```

means you used `Recipes` instead of `Recipe` somewhere (line 4 in `index`) in controller, and since your model is called `Recipe` (singular), you're getting `NameError` exception.